# Hibernate mapping setting lazy = 'false'

Tags: hibernate, mapping, fetch, lazy-evaluation

In hibernate mapping, I have set the property `lazy="false"`, and this fetches all the child records of the parent.

This is being used throughout the application.
This creates a performance issue at a particular module of my application, wherein I would like to fetch only the parent record.

I cant change the `lazy` property to `true` since it's being used at many other places. Is there a way to fix this?

Do let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These is no such feature in hibernate as it respects your `lazy="false"`. So, what can I suggest to address your requirement is extends your querying class with another dummy concrete class and define mapping for that class without that child association in it.

let say you have class Parent with Child mapping in it

```
class Parent{

     private List<Child> kids;

}
```

and mapping for Parent you have is

```
<class name="Parent" table="PARENT">
// other properties
// child mapping
   <set name="kids" table="KIDS" lazy="false">
       <key column="parent_id"/>
       <one-to-many class="Child"/>
   </set>
</class>
```

Then you can create another class which extends Parent class

```
class MinimalParent extends Parent{
   // leave implementation as blank
}
```

Then map it as bellow

```
<class name="MinimalParent" table="PARENT">
    // other properties
    // do not map child in this
</class>
```

And use this `MinimalParent` class wherever you require just parent object. hope you got it!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I'm pretty new to hibernate could you tell me how to go about it?

Comment: @Pokuri if I don't map the child properties then how will I get the proxies?

Comment: @Pokuri can you answer my question?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably set lazy="true" to fetch only parent as a default, and use JPQL queries with "fetch join" to fetch parent together with children wherever it is required, e.g.:

```
SELECT mag FROM Magazine mag JOIN FETCH mag.articles WHERE mag.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This cannot be done since it means changing a lot of code where this is used. Is there any other alternative?